# abbreviate elasticsearch values

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am using elasticsearch to extract some values but they are quite large and i want to abbreviate them to small values. I am using scripted fields to do my abbreviation using if else statements. I am actually trying to change the dept value.

when i run this i still return the same value. Is there a problem in the query ?

```
{
  "query": {
    // query with some filters 
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "abbreviated_dept": {
      "script": {
        "source": "def dept = doc['dept'].value; if (dept == 'Elasticsearch_tech') { return 'ET'; } else if (dept == 'Market_search') { return 'MS'; } else if (dept == 'InfoIN_search') { return 'IIS'; } else { return dept; }"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response i get is a table with Dept and dept count like

```
Dept               Dept Count
Elasticsearch_tech  14
Market_search       10
InfoIN_search        6
FS                   4
PS                   2
```

Comment: Can you show the response you get?

Comment: Added in the original post. Thanks !

Comment: I'm thinking about the raw JSON response you get from your query